# How to check if input isnt an INTwith a try/catch while loop

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, null, try-catch

Im trying to make UNO. & when the user enters a NUMBER for how many players, I want to be able to check back if they dont enter a number such as a letter or symbol.... Does player != (int)players  not work? Because it ends up in an infinite loop saying null try again

do {
                    try {

```
                    int players = s.nextInt();
                    if (players < 2 || players > 4) throw new Exception ("Only 2-4 players allowed");
                    else if (players != (int)players) throw new Exception ("ENTRY MUST BE AN INTEGER");
                    else {

                        checkPlayers = true;
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception playersAmount) {

                    System.out.println(playersAmount.getMessage() + "\nTry Again.");

                }
        }
        while (checkPlayers == false);
        System.out.println("ESCAPED");
```

Comment: No that does not.  if s.nextInt() doesn't return an int you don't have an int.   Now what does s ref, Scanner?

Comment: yes s is Scanner

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use exceptions to control the flow of your program. You can do simple checks and output errors to System.out and keep the flow of your program dependent on variables. Here is a simple while to get input from the user until they enter 2-4. Also you need to declare players outside your while loop so you can use that variable after you've received a valid number of players for your game.

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean checkPlayers = false;
    int players = -1;
    while(!checkPlayers)
    {
        String input = s.nextLine();
        if(input.matches("\\d++"))
        {
            players = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if(players <= 4 && players > 1)
            {
                checkPlayers = true;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Only 2-4 players allowed");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("ENTRY MUST BE AN INTEGER");

    }
    System.out.println("Number of players is: " + players);
```